# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create not working on spring boot 1.5

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

this is my **application.dev.properties**

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
datasource.dev.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
datasource.dev.username=gdpr_root
datasource.dev.password=computer@1234
datasource.dev.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Drive
```

This is for common **application.properties**

```
props.hb.hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size=1000
props.hb.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
props.hb.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I have  tried to add  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` on both properties files.
but not creating the table structure.
i have followed below stack links

[Unable to get spring boot to automatically create database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881739/unable-to-get-spring-boot-to-automatically-create-database-schema)

[Auto creating tables failed in Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140163/auto-creating-tables-failed-in-spring-jpa/41829372)

expecting a better solution for my issue.
**Edit 1**
schema will create but tables not created yet

Comment: Judging from your config you are using multiple datasources, meaning manual configuration of those as well, which would probably also mean manual configuration of the entitymanager and thus the auto config options will not work.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum for the quick update